# How can I refer to an object that has been replaced by a new one?

Tags: phrase-request, adjectives

I was on another SE forum and I wanted to speak about the fridge I was using before the new one I bought, I referred to it like this:

> my old fridge

Is that a good way to do it? Whether it is or not, are there other ways to say it ?

Comment: That's exactly what I would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My old fridge" is a great way to do it because it's probably the most common way people would talk about it. If you need an alternate, here are some other ways that would be acceptable:

- My prior fridge.
- My previous fridge.
- The fridge I had before this one.
- The piece of junk I had before my current fridge. ('piece of junk' can be replaced by some notable feature of the previous fridge)
- The fridge that I recently(?) got rid of.
- The fridge I replaced (with my current one).

There are plenty of ways you can refer to the prior fridge, although some are more specific than others.

Comment: Ok thank you ! And does the signification of the word old depends of the context here ? Because in French if I say "vieux frigo" (which is the French for "old fridge") it doesn't means that I replaced it, it simply means that is have a fridge which is old.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Yes, context would matter - with "prior" and "previous" there is no ambiguity at all. "Old" has come to be conflated with "previous" because that's what you do with old things - you replace them! Most people would understand "old" the way you used it as "previous" without any context because if you current fridge was old you probably wouldn't mention it was old except directly: "My fridge is old".  On the other hand, if the person you're talking to knows your current fridge is old, they might assume you're talking about your current one unless you clarify.